# Graphviz: xlabel position

Tags: graphviz, dotfiles

I have nodes in my diagram with their xlabels positioned left above them. How can I change this position? I want the xlabels to be exactly next to the node itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[xlp](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:xlp) is the attribute you want, but it doesn't do anything.

You can't change the position because xlp is "write only", which indicates that the attribute is used for output, and is not used or read by any of the layout programs.